# Google map store locator

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Hi im working through the Creating a store locator tutorial on google that can be found here.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

My code is

```
    // Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string("37.414832"),
  mysql_real_escape_string("-122.024857"),
  mysql_real_escape_string("37.414832"),
  mysql_real_escape_string("10"));


$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) 
{
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
}

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<markers>\n";
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}


// End XML file
echo "</markers>\n";
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

However when I run the script I get the error message

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Can anybody see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code differs significantly from the example. Have you quoted everything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$dom` object you are trying to create a  element for doesn't exist before the 'while' loop.
Create that DOMDocument object first and include the `<markers>` rootnode in that object.